# Why do you need three perpendicular bisectors to circumscribe a triangle?

Tags: geometry

All the perpendicular bisectors of the sides of a triangle intersect at one point -- the circumcenter. So, why do we typically find all three perpendicular bisectors when trying to circumscribe a triangle in a circle? Wouldn't two perpendicular bisectors be sufficient to find the radius of the circle since the third perpendicular bisector would intersect in the same place anyway?

Comment: I have always used two and I think people normally use two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, even though this isn't what you asked, I wanted to explain why the 3 perpendicular bisectors are concurrent in the first place, and why they intersect at the circumcenter.

Basically, in order to circumscribe a triangle using a circle, you need to find the point that is equidistant from each of the vertices in the triangle. A perpendicular bisector of a segment AB is actually the set of all points that are equidistant from A and B. You can see this by picking an arbitrary point C on the line, and the intersection of the perpendicular bisector of AB with AB D. It is easy to see that AD=DB, CD=CD, and m<ADC=<BDC=90º. Therefore, triangles ADC and BDC are congruent by SAS, so AC=BC.

Now let's focus on the triangle in question. Call it XYZ. Call line z the perpendicular bisector of XY, y the bisector of XZ, and x the bisector of YZ. The intersection of x and z is the point equidistant from X, Y, and Z, and since two lines can only intersect at one point, there is only one point with this property, This means that, since x and y also intersect at a point with this property, and the only point with that property is the intersection of x and z, we know that x, y, and z must be concurrent at the point equidistant from X, Y, and Z, called the circumcenter of triangle XYZ.

So, yes, you can find the circumcenter using only two perpendicular bisectors, but using 3 is usually a good thing to do since if they don't concur at the same point you know you made a mistake :)